# Disable Validation on all items inside a panel

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

is it possible to disable validation of all items inside a panel programatically in vb.net?

i can't seem to figure it out.

i disabled all fields inside a panel, but they still cause the page to validate on submit.

this is what i have now:

> ```
> Public Sub DisableControls(ByVal parent As Control)
>     Dim cCon As Control
>     For Each cCon In parent.Controls
>         If (TypeOf cCon Is TextBox) Then
>             CType(cCon, TextBox).Enabled = False
>             CType(cCon, TextBox).CausesValidation = False
>         End If
>         If (TypeOf cCon Is DropDownList) Then
>             CType(cCon, DropDownList).Enabled = False
>             CType(cCon, DropDownList).CausesValidation = False
>         End If
>     Next
> End Sub
> ```

it disables the controls just fine,but validations till works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CausesValidation` just disables the behavior of your controls so that when one of them causes a post-back, validation is skipped.

You have to disable validators.